# Error while using default value in parameter of Protocol's method

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I have a method in Protocol and using this method so many times. Now I need to add one more parameter in that method. I just need to pass that parameter in one case. So I have added default value in that parameter. But protocol doesn't accept default value. So what I did is:

```
protocol TestP {
    func update(srId: String, srType: String? )
}

class Test: TestP {
    func update(srId: String, srType: String? = "") {
        print("abc")
    }
}

let test: TestP = Test()
test.update(srId: "abc")
```

But here I am getting error
**`error: missing argument for parameter 'srType' in call`** because at compile time it check method in Protocol and do not find default value for `srType`. So I try adding same method in extension of Protocol as given:

```
extension TestP {
    func update(srId: String, srType: String? = "") {
        print("abc")
    }
}
```

Here class `Test` method should be called because the object is of class `Test`. But every time protocol's method is being called. I don't know what is wrong with my code? How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use following method signature:

```
extension TestP {
    func update(srId: String) {
        update(srId: srId, srType: "")
    }
}
```

Because if you want to pass `srType` in the call you already have the method `func update(srId: String, srType: String?)` in the protocol.

> There is no need to use parameter with default value.

Call with default value:

```
let test: TestP = Test()
test.update(srId: "abc")
```

Call with `srType` parameter:

```
let test: TestP = Test()
test.update(srId: "abc", srType: "type")
```

Answer (score 3):

Update protocol extension with below code

Extension provides the default values, calling original protocol function with those default values

```
extension TestP {
    func update(srId: String, srType: String? = "") {
        update(srId: srId, srType: srType)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell why it is calling extension method every time when I have object of `Test` class?

Comment: It is only called when you pass only one parameter in update function of protocol

Comment: you can try with two parameter in update function of protocol that time protocol extension not calling